# Difficult to implement a Test setup using libs like Zustand in my React Application. ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocking, local-storage, zustand

I'm trying to implement a setup of tests for my React application. So the first thing I had to do was implement some mocks, like authentications, localStorage and etc. I've created a localStorageMock to save a JSON webtoken for my application when I was testing it, but for some reason the zustand store there I use to get the token, can't find my localStorageMock. And it keep saying the ***ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined***. With my test setup I always put my localStorageMock to start before each test.

1º - useAuthStore:

```
export const useAuthStore = create<AuthenticationsStore>((set) => ({
    authentication: {
        token: localStorage.getItem('token') || ('' as string),
        permissions: [],
        originalGroupId: 0,
    },
    setAuthentication: (authentication) =>
        set(() => ({
            authentication: authentication,
        })),
    setPermissions: (permissions: string[]) =>
        set((state) => ({
            authentication: {
                ...state.authentication,
                permissions: permissions,
            },
        })),
    setToken: (token: string) =>
        set((state) => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            return {
                authentication: {
                    ...state.authentication,
                    token: token,
                },
            };
        }),
    setOriginalGroupId: (originalGroupId: number) =>
        set((state) => ({
            authentication: {
                ...state.authentication,
                originalGroupId: originalGroupId,
            },
        })),
    dismissAuthentication: () =>
        set(() => {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return {
                authentication: {
                    token: '',
                    permissions: [],
                    originalGroupId: 0,
                },
            };
        }),
}));
```

2º - LocalStorageMock

```
export class LocalStorageMock implements Storage {
    private store: Record<string, string>;

    constructor() {
        this.store = {};
    }

    getItem(key: string): string | null {
        return this.store[key] || null;
    }

    setItem(key: string, value: string): void {
        this.store[key] = value.toString();
    }

    removeItem(key: string): void {
        delete this.store[key];
    }

    clear(): void {
        this.store = {};
    }

    // Implementação das propriedades da interface Storage
    // Adapte conforme necessário
    get length(): number {
        return Object.keys(this.store).length;
    }

    key(index: number): string | null {
        const keys = Object.keys(this.store);
        return index >= 0 && index < keys.length ? keys[index] : null;
    }
}

global.localStorage = new LocalStorageMock();
```

3º - My Test Implementation.

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import PaginaInicial from '../../../features/inicial/routes/PaginaInicial';
import { accessToken } from '../../utils/globalMocks/access-token-json.mock.';
import { LocalStorageMock } from '../../utils/globalMocks/localStorage.mock';
import 'mock-local-storage';

describe('Página Inicial', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        if (!global.localStorage) {
            global.localStorage = new LocalStorageMock();
        }
        global.localStorage.setItem(
            'token',
            accessToken.token_type + ' ' + accessToken.access_token,
        );
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        global.localStorage.clear();
    });

    test('Renderização componentes página inicial', async () => {
        render(<PaginaInicial />);
        // Restante do seu código de teste
    });
});
```

4º - The Error

[image]

I tryied to find a solution on the web, on the zustand lib and with chatGPT. But I can't find and solution to this. I was excpecting when I create localstorage globally it will work as usual, but for some reason with the lib there is something that I really don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across to access localstorage on my test cases while writing with jest.

solved it by adding the below block in my `index.test.tsx`

```
// imports

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
  value: new MockLocalStorage()
})

describe(()=> {
   test(()=>{})
   test(()=>{})
})
```

Instead of adding it to the global put it into the window, would love to know better answer if any!